# Roundcube не отправляет почту - dovecot_login authenticator failed

Tags: linux, debian, exim, vesta, roundcube

У меня стоит VestaCP на Debian 8, столкнулся с проблемой, что `mail()` вроде как отлично отправляет почту, но на деле письмо не доходит. Зашел в web-интерфейс Roundcube и решил от туда отправить почту, но там тоже пишет что все "ок", а по факту ничего нет.

Начал копать логи и вот что нашел:

**/var/log/exim4/mainlog**

```
2018-09-18 13:31:02 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (мой IP) [185.234.219.254]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=judy)
2018-09-18 13:31:06 1g2G5q-0006SL-7M <= support@мойсайт.com U=ark P=local S=837 id=97e8d0a7d3fc2e8ced6a95f6b00e7ccf@мойсайт.com
2018-09-18 13:33:11 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (User) [185.234.219.30]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=jenny)
2018-09-18 13:33:16 1g2G5q-0006SL-7M alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [108.177.125.27] Connection timed out
2018-09-18 13:33:16 1g2G5q-0006SL-7M == получатель@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2018-09-18 13:33:22 no IP address found for host cvcmailer.com (during SMTP connection from [81.4.126.78])
2018-09-18 13:33:24 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (localhost) [81.4.126.78]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=admin@мой сайт.com)
```

**/var/log/exim4/reject**

```
2018-09-18 14:10:37 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (User) [185.234.219.30]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=armando)
2018-09-18 14:11:38 1g2Gj4-0007MC-Ci <= support@мойсайт.com U=ark P=local S=684 id=93b9dfe318b190eaf8a493c9ff1b3af0@мойсайт.com
2018-09-18 14:11:38 1g2Gj4-0007MC-Ci == получатель@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
2018-09-18 14:12:36 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (мой IP) [185.234.219.254]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=login)
2018-09-18 14:15:58 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (User) [185.234.219.30]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=brenda)
```

Почта не отправляется, но зато если посылаю себе на support@мойсайт.com то все приходит.

Comment: Здесь написано, что ваш логин-пароль, с котором вы пытаетесь авторизоваться на SMTP-сервере, не совпадает с теми, которые есть у него.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev , как я это могу исправить?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev __У меня стоит VestaCP__ видимо в панели весты исправить пароль на почтовом ящике

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, нет, не там точно